# Failure to build QEMU version 0.15.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, cross-platform, qemu

I am trying to build an old version of QEMU (version 0.15.1) on Ubuntu version 16.04.

I configured it using this command:

> ./configure --target-list=i386-linux-user,arm-linux-user
>   --python=/usr/bin/python2.7

When I run "make" command, these errors are produced:

> syscall.o: In function `do_syscall':
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7841:
>   undefined reference to`mq_timedreceive'
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7813:
>   undefined reference to `mq_unlink'
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7824:
>   undefined reference to`mq_timedsend' syscall.o: In function
>   `mq_open': /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mqueue2.h:56: undefined
>   reference to`mq_open' syscall.o: In function `do_syscall':
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7828:
>   undefined reference to`mq_send'
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7845:
>   undefined reference to `mq_receive'
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7866:
>   undefined reference to`mq_setattr'
>   /home/asus/Thesis_project/old_qemu/qemu-0.15.1/linux-user/syscall.c:7861:
>   undefined reference to `mq_getattr' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status Makefile:398: recipe for target 'qemu-i386' failed
>   make[1]: *** [qemu-i386] Error 1 Makefile:84: recipe for target
>   'subdir-i386-linux-user' failed make: *** [subdir-i386-linux-user]
>   Error 2

Comment: The sequence "sudo apt-get build-dep qemu; apt-get source --compile qemu" might  help. It will install the right dependencies and will give a hint on which ./configure options are usable.

Comment: But I am building qemu from the source, as I need a certain version (0.15.1) ... the current version of QEMU is 2.9 I think.
So will the command you mentioned, will get latest QEMU in Ubuntu package ?

Comment: I'm going to argue that just because this contains references to C files, doesn't mean it is an actual C issue. Reconsider your use of the tag.

Comment: Is it possible that the mq_* functions have been moved to librt.so? A text search on /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ indicates so. So maybe add -lrt when linking.

Comment: what does -lrt do ?

Comment: It instructs the linker to look inside librt for symbols

Answer (score 0):

I have added LIBS+=-lrt to the file Makefile.target, and it is now working.
Thanks Konrad.